# JS/PHP библиотека для рисования геометрических рисунков

Tags: svg, canvas, php, геометрия, javascript

Добрый день.
Кто-нибудь встречал js библиотеку, работающую с svg/canvas/css или создающую изображение/другое_наглядное_средство_представления_рисунка силами php, которая по данным может нарисовать рисунок задачи по геометрии?

Comment: А можно поподробнее, как вы себе это представляете? Есть такие библиотеки, что бы создавать изображения в PHP, есть библиотеки для JS, но принцип работы "js библиотеки работающую силами php" я представить не могу.

Comment: [Raphael][1] подойдёт?

[1]: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: автор, ваш вопрос начисто лишен здравого смысла - js/canvas это клиентская технология, т.е. это что-то одно, а средства манипуляций с графикой на php - серверная технология, т.е. что-то совершенно другое

Comment: @deivan, я постарался дать два варианта - либо серверное решение, либо клиентское.